# Confusion in creating a directed graph in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to create a directed graph by reading a text file where each line has two columns, first column is a tail vertex and second column is the head vertex. Presently just to test if my code works I am trying to populate the graph and print it out.

I am printing my graph after every node insertion. Graph print works as fine until I insert the third node "4" after which first node changes to 0 from 1. I do not have any clue why. I wonder if storing node pointers in edge is a good idea. I am doing it because I already have node information in the "nodes" vector hence do not want to duplicate it.

Input test file:

```
1 2
4 5
```

My data structures are:
 node: which holds node id and and boolean variable node dirty
 edge: which holds pointers to tail node and head node
 graph: Holds vectors of all nodes and edges

Output:

```
Pushing :1
print called
Nodes are:
1

Pushing :2
print called
Nodes are:
1
2

Pushing :4
print called
0(0) --> 2(0)     // Problem this should have been 1(0) --> 2(0)
Nodes are:
1
2
4



#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    node() {}
    node(int _nodeId, bool dirty);
    int nodeId;
    bool dirty;
    void operator=(node rhs);
    bool operator==(node rhs);
};

class edge {
public:
    edge(node *_startNode, node *_endNode): startNode(_startNode), endNode(_endNode) {}
    node *startNode, *endNode;
};



node :: node(int _nodeId, bool _dirty) {
    nodeId = _nodeId;
    dirty = _dirty;
}

void node :: operator=(node rhs) {
    this->dirty = rhs.dirty;
    this->nodeId = rhs.nodeId;
}

bool node :: operator==(node rhs) {
    if (this->nodeId == rhs.nodeId) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



class graph {
public:
    void print();
    void addEdge(node startNode, node endNode);
    void addNode(node n);
    void dfs(node s);
private:
    vector<edge> edges;
    vector<node> nodes;
};

void graph :: addNode(node n) {
    // only add this node if it does not exist in the graph
    if (find(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), n) == nodes.end()) {
        //print();
        cout <<  "Pushing :"<<n.nodeId<<endl;
        nodes.push_back(n);
    }
    print();
    cout << endl;
}

void graph :: dfs(node s) {
    // Search node s and mark it as dirty


}
void graph :: print() {
    cout << "print called\n";
    vector<edge>::iterator itr = edges.begin();
    while (itr != edges.end()) {
        cout << itr->startNode->nodeId << "("<< itr->startNode->dirty<<") --> ";
        cout << itr->endNode->nodeId << "("<< itr->endNode->dirty<<")"<<endl;
        ++itr;
    }

    cout << "Nodes are:\n";
    for (int i=0; i< nodes.size(); ++i) {
        cout << nodes.at(i).nodeId << endl;
    }
}

void graph :: addEdge(node startNode, node endNode) {
    vector<node>::iterator itrStartNode;
    itrStartNode = find(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), startNode);
    vector<node>::iterator itrEndNode;
    itrEndNode = find(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), endNode);
    edge e(&(*itrStartNode), &(*itrEndNode));
    edges.push_back(e);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    graph g;
    // Read the file here
    ifstream file;
    file.open("test.txt", ios::in);
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        int startNodeId, endNodeId;
        istringstream is(line);
        is >> startNodeId >> endNodeId;
        node startNode(startNodeId, false);
        node endNode(endNodeId, false);
        g.addNode(startNode);
        g.addNode(endNode);
        g.addEdge(startNode, endNode);
    }
    file.close();
    g.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating temporary variables, *e.g.*

```
        node startNode(startNodeId, false);
        node endNode(endNodeId, false);
```

and

```
    edge e(&(*itrStartNode), &(*itrEndNode));
```

and storing pointers to temporary instances into your containers, *e.g.*

```
    edge e(&(*itrStartNode), &(*itrEndNode));
    edges.push_back(e);
```

Once you exit the local scope in which those instances were created (the `while` loop or the `addEdge` method), the stack memory storing those instances are taken back by the program for use elsewhere. However, your *pointers* still point to valid memory addresses (taken back by the program or not), and so, may still point to valid-seeming data. That's probably what's going on, *i.e.* why you're seeing valid-seeming but incorrect vertices.

Use the `new` operator to create instances that persist beyond the local scopes of loops and functions, and clean them up (via `delete`) appropriately.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying...but I am unable to make it to work :) . I changed my addNode and addEdge procedures to create new nodes and edges like this: `node *nn = new node;
        nn->nodeId = n.nodeId;
        nn->dirty = n.dirty;
        nodes.push_back(*nn);`  and similarly addEdge: 
    `edge *e = new edge;
    e->startNode = &(*itrStartNode);
    e->endNode = &(*itrEndNode);
    edges.push_back(*e);` but it does not work same problem!

Comment: Okay...I figured it out...using new operator inside the `addEdge` and `addNode` will not help since variables defined inside these procs will be lost ass soon as fn call is finished. Hence this needs to be done inside `main`. Thanks for the help!!